# как создать раздел

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет. Недавно начал разбираться с битриксом, взял тестовый проект и вот вотпрос - как добавить раздел, чтобы он в списке слева был после раздела "Закупки"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Типы информационных блоков > Добавить новый тип

Comment: тип появился во вкладке "инфоблоки", но вот здесь сверху все равно все теже разделы остались

Comment: То есть мне нужно чтобы он появился после определенного инфоблока, потому что щас он появляется не после того раздела, после которого мне нужно

Comment: там есть свойство сортировка у всех по умолчанию 500, пересортируйте

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю что нужно просто поменять значение в своистве сортировка, и это ни не чем не отразится, так? (только на расположении ?)